# How do I get this formula to respond with a calculation or text from cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am a contractor and use excel to create budgets for our jobs with a main budget sheet and another one I submit to customers.

On the main budget sheet I either have a numeric cost for doing said work or a text value saying `TBD` or `NIC` or `By Owner` depending on the line item.

I am trying to write a formula that will go to the cover page, retrieve either the dollar amount or the typed text.  If there is a numeric value I would like to then add 10% to the the said number.

So right now my formula is this;

`=(Cover!D17 *10%)+Cover!D17)`

But if on the main page I have a word written the formula comes back as an error.

How do I get this formula to respond with a calculation or text from cell?

Comment: Your formula can't possibly work as it is, given that you have 1 ( and 2 )'s. That said, you want to use an IF to see what the content is and based on that, either do formula X or formula Y.

Answer (score 2):

You can test a value to see if it is a number with ISNUMBER(). And you can use the IF() function to do different things based on the result of ISNUMBER(). In a simple worksheet, if you had a number or text in A1, and you wanted to multiply A1 by 10% only if A1 is a number, your formula would look like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1), A1*10%, "False")
```

You can do whatever you need to do with the false condition. I'm just having it write "False" in the cell, but most any expression can go there.

ISNUMBER() returns a boolean value, either true or false. The first step in the IF() function needs something that can result in a boolean value. If the test evaluates to true, IF() does what's after the first comma. If the test evaluates to false, IF() does what's after the second comma. The way it works is often presented like this:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

But rather than a value, what you'll often want is an expression of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of [`IF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) and [`IS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) statements you can make this work.

The `IF` statement has Excel check for logical condition (TRUE or FALSE).

> IF(Something is True, then do something, otherwise do something else)

The `ISNUMBER` function checks the content of a cell to see if it's value is a number (TRUE or FALSE).

You formula will look like this;

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Cover!D17), SUM(Cover!D17+(Cover!D17*0.1)), Cover!D17)
```

The `IF` is checking the return of the `ISNUMBER` statement. If it is true, it returns the value of `Cover!D17` plus 10% by using the formula `SUM(Cover!D17+(Cover!D17*0.1))`. If `ISNUMBER` returns false, the value of `Cover!D17` will be returned.

**Note: If `Cover!D17` is formatted as text, this will not work.**